# How do I get input from user in the first problem set of cs50?

Tags: java, c, cs50, edx

I'm required to implement the `get_string` method in order to ask user for input but I'm having trouble running the program though I think I have followed the steps correctly.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)
{ string name = get_string("What is your name?\n");

   // string name= get_string("What is your name, huh? \n"); 
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

Now to run the program, I type in `./hi` ( hi is the folder name) to compile and the ls.. 
when I type `clang hello.c` ( hello.c is the name of the file I'm writing in) I get error.. 
I do not understand the difference between `clang hello.c` and `./hi` ..

Comment: What is the error message?  Note that `clang hello.c` is the command to compile the code - if it produces an executable named `hi` (`clang -o hi hello.c`), then `./hi` would run the program.  If `hi` is a directory name, then `./hi` doesn’t do anything useful.

Comment: Here's the error message : $ clang -o hi hello.c
/tmp/hello-5cfed3.o: In function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `get_string'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running clang, try running `$ make hello.c` This should make a file named hello. The terminal will also show you all the compiler arguments CS50 has added to clang. You should then be able to run using `$ ./hello`